# Did the Sixers hesitate in Ready Player One?

Tags: ready-player-one

In *Ready Player One* by Ernest Cline, toward the end

> when Wade/Parzival is at IOI, he discovers that the Sixers know the physical locations of both Art3mis, and Shoto. Why didn't the Sixers kill them as soon as they knew where they were, as they did with Daito? Wade was there for several days, so presumably IOI had been sitting on that information for some time. Since both IOI and the four gunters already knew the location of the last gate, keeping Art3mis and Shoto alive wasn't advantageous to the Sixers at that point.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To be pedantic the sixers are the avatars of IOI employees and so don't actually exist in the real world ;)

To answer your question though on the last page of chapter 30 it's revealed the Nolan Sorento proposes that IOI abduct Art3mis and Shoto and force them to help open the third gate and then 'dispose' of them afterwards. So killing them is not part of the plan. On the same page we're given the time the message was sent and an explanation that Sorentos superiors probably hadn't seen the memo yet.

This gives Wade a small window in which he can escape IOI and warn them and he gives himself till dawn. In chapter 31 we see that the first thing he does when he escapes the following morning is go to a postal rental outlis where he has gear waiting and he warns them.

In short it was Sorentos idea but he had to clear it with the bosses and Wade got the message before they did.

Comment: The book doesn't distinguish between calling the employees of IOI "sixers" only when referring to their in game avatars so I don't think its too big of a deal to refer to them as sixers in all cases.

Comment: "clearing it with the bosses" being the main reason

Comment: +1 - In addition the email that Sorento sent to his superiors was very recent regarding the idea to either kill/capture them which is why Wade accelerated his plan and escaped prior to his initial "pay off" date. While they had known their locations for some time they had not really needed their help until they became stumped on the third gate. And as Sorento mentions when he first threatened Wade "IOI might need their help in the future"...